# Understand meaning of {...} when creating objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across the following code

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::string inputfilename, outputfilename;

    std::cin  >> outputfilename;

    std::ofstream outputfile{ outputfilename };

    outputfile << "I exist Yo!";

    return 0;
}
```

My first reaction was that it should not compile. I had never seen the `outputfile{ outputfilename };` syntax. Can someone please tell me what feature of the C++ language defines the behavior of `{...}` in this line of code?

P.S. The code works and does what you would expect.

Comment: Read about [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization).

Comment: it's just a new way to write the constructor arguments that was introduced in c++ 11. It should be the same as `std::ofstream outputfile(outputfilename);`

Comment: @Arne Thanks. You mean std::ofstream outputfile(outputfilename.c_str())  ;)

Comment: @user3670482: No. `std::ofstream outputfile(outputfilename)` has been valid since 2011. You're way out of date, man!

Comment: Incidentally, how do you add code inside comments

Comment: @user3670482 That's also been changed in C++11, the stream constructors now can handle `std::string` objects. :)

Comment: @user3670482: There's a "help" link by the comment input box. Click on it.

Comment: How is a 9-month member not aware of those stackexchange formattings? It appears everywhere in most questions

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I had not noticed the help button. May I suggest making it bigger/bolder or something similar.

Comment: When you click in any comment textbox or the big question/answer editor, there is a help link appears for you. There's also a big help button on the top bar

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I stand happily corrected :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the C++11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> **8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]**
>
> 1 *List-initialization* is initialization of an object or reference from a *braced-init-list*. Such an initializer is called an initializer list, and the comma-separated *initializer-clauses* of the list are called the *elements* of the initializer list. An initializer list may be empty. *List-initialization* can occur in *direct-initialization* or *copy-initialization* contexts; *list-initialization* in a *direct-initialization* context is called *direct-list-initialization* and *list-initialization* in a *copy-initialization* context is called *copy-list-initialization*. [ Note: *List-initialization* can be used
>
> - as the initializer in a variable definition (8.5)
> - as the initializer in a new expression (5.3.4)
> - in a return statement (6.6.3)
> - as a function argument (5.2.2)
> - as a subscript (5.2.1)
> - **as an argument to a constructor invocation (8.5, 5.2.3)**
> - *[..]*

Comment: What advantage does using list-initialization have (here)?

Comment: List-initialization was introduced in C++11 to overcome some of the challenges in initializing objects in C++03. See the [Uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization).

Comment: @ user2864740: List-initialization syntax happens to be that common syntax that works in all initialization contexts. In a *specific* context its advantages might not be obvious (yet they exist), but once you take the bigger picture into account, the global *uniformity* of the syntax alone is already a huge advantage.

Comment: How many books do I have to read before I could read and understand the standard by itself?

Comment: @user3670482, it's a combination of reading the standard, reading commentary on the standard, reading books, writing a lot of code, and learning from each as you go.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks. What do you recommend doing first? Reading advanced books like Effective C++, Effective Modern C++, or reading the standard? Or do you recommend I do both in unison?

Comment: @user3670482, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list.